# Infinite Time Turing Machine and Hypertask

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, turing-machines

Good Day,

I would like to ask this question.
Infinite Time Turing Machine ordinals are countable ordinals. Also I have read that ITTM either halts or repeats itselve after countably many steps.

Does that mean that ITTMs are not able of doing hypertask, which is defined as doing uncountably many computational steps in finite time (by uncountably many I mean the cardinality of Reals so assume Continuum hypothesis is true)?

Also If that is true, may I ask you of some kind of problem (other than halting problem for ITTMs) that ITTMs would not be able to solve but hypercomputer capable of hypertask would be able to solve?

Thank you very much for your kind answers.

EDIT: Maybe the question is better asked this way: Lets have hypercomputer capable of doing ℵ1 operations in finite time, where those operations are equivalent with operations that CISC cpu can do. This machine can take input with maximum length of ℵ1 bits and can take programs with length at most ℵ1 bits.
Is this hypercomputer more powerul then ITTM? What kind of problems could it solve that ITTM could not?

Comment: Before this question can be answered we need a more precise notion of "hypertask" - just saying that it can do uncountably many computational steps in finite time doesn't actually constitute a definition.

Comment: You might want to read about Ordinal Turing Machines.

Comment: Also, note that the cardinality of the reals is uncountable regardless of CH, or any other reasonable assumption for that matter.

Comment: @Vsotvep Yes, I just meant to say that lets assume it is the smallest uncountable set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So would you think this is sufficient?: Able to perform the same number of operations as is the cardinality of continuum in finite time and when it comes to operations it could do the same operations as a CISC CPU could. Also lets assume the memory is unconstraint so we have as much memory as we need. Also input can be of uncountable length (again cardinality of reals) EDIT: Also it can work with programs of uncountable length

Comment: *I just meant to say that lets assume it is the smallest uncountable set* --- I don't see how CH plays any nontrivial role in what you are asking. If CH fails, for example suppose $2^{{\aleph}_{0}} = {\aleph}_{42},$ then what effect would this have on your question?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It would affect it, because ℵ1 < ℵ42 and I wanted to ask if the least powerful hypercomputer capable of doing uncountable number of operations is more powerful than ITTM

Comment: Then why not just say that a hypertask does $\aleph_1$ operations? No need to involve the reals or the CH

Comment: @Vsotvep well those statements are equivalent so this seems pointles. But yes I can say it like this. Is the hypercomputer capable of performing ℵ1 operations where those operations are those of CISC CPU on input of length at most ℵ1 bits with program with length at most ℵ1 bits more powerful then ITTM?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have edited my question with (hopefully) better definition of hypertask